# What is Eisenbud's justification for the following step in his Commutative Algebra text (Proposition 6.1)?

Tags: commutative-algebra, proof-explanation

To put this into context, I was doing a reading on the text with my mentor and the following step proved to be unjustifiable to the both of us.

The step I am referring to is the paragraph that goes "Similarly, the module $N\otimes M$ is generated by the elements ..."

In particular, I am confused on how Eisenbud is able to justify that $N$ is finitely generated just because the relations of bilinearity of $N\otimes M$ involves finitely many elements.

Besides this step, the rest of the proof makes sense to me. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: It's basically a direct limit argument: $M\otimes N$ is the direct limit of $M'\otimes N$ where $M'$ ranges over the f.g. submodules of $M$.

Comment: It is not that $N$ is proven to be finitely generated, but that one passes to the submodule generated by the finitely many elements involved in the condition $f(x)=0$ and the rest of the argument is done for that submodule. Note the 'we may assume'.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with arguments using direct limits and don't feel comfortable with doing such an argument as of right now. Would you perhaps clarify in more details on how it is done?

Comment: Don't worry about direct limits, all that means in this case is that $N$ is the union of all finitely generated submodules that it contains. Injectivity is proving that $f(x)=0\implies x=0$. So, it doesn't matter if for each $x$ such that $f(x)=0$ you restrict $f$ to some finitely generated submodule that contains $x$ and prove that $x=0$.

Comment: The key words here are *we may assume* which is usually shorthand for reasoning that an implication statement with an extra hypothesis implies the implication statement without the extra hypothesis.  (Simpler example: suppose we want to prove $\max(x,y) + \min(x,y) = x + y$ for $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$.  A proof might start: "by symmetry, *we may assume* $x \le y$.  What this really means is that $(\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R},x\le y\rightarrow\cdots)\rightarrow(\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R},\cdots)$, *not* that in all cases $x \le y$.

Comment: Okay, I think I'm starting to understand the reduction being done here. I'll think about it for a bit and see if I believe the step.